# What is recommended approach for storing SharePoint web part images?

Tags: sharepoint

I am little confused with available approaches to store my web part images. I found that i can store images which are being used in my Web Part at following different location 
1. [12Hive]/TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS/1033/IMAGES
2. 80/wpresources/[AssemblyName]
3. [12Hive]/TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS/[Project specific folder]/Images/

Can any one suggest when to use which approach ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should store them in the _images virtual directory (.../12/template/layouts/images on disc), in a new, project specific subdirectory, and reference them in your application using _images/My_Dir/My_Image.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is  \12hive\TEMPLATE\IMAGES
3rd option is also not bad.

Answer (score 0):

/wpresources/[AssemblyName] is ok for Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart derived web parts, because you can reference the location from within the web part using this.ClassResourcePath.

This is not available in System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart derived web parts though.

Answer (score 0):

I use 12\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\MyProject.

You can then reference it in any page or css file as '_layouts/images/myproject/myimage.gif'.